# Computing $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}z^2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ dz \ dy \ dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^²}}z^2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ dz \ dy \ dx$$

Transforming to spherical coordinates I have that $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-r^2\sin^2\varphi}} r^2\cos^2 \varphi\ \cdot r^3 \ d\varphi \ d\theta \ dr$$

but this is very hard to compute, I feel like I'm missing something here? The additional $r$ to form the cubic comes from the Jacobian.

Comment: I don't think you have transformed to spherical coordinates $r,\theta, \phi$  as you still have a $z dz$ there. Surely it's an integral over a sphere $r\leqslant 2$?

Comment: That looks more like *cylindrical* coordinates to me.

Comment: I forgot to write $z$ as spherical coordinates. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are integrating over is 1/8th of a ball of radius 2. It will be easier to integrate over the entire ball and divide by 8 (since this function is "even").

$8\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^²}}z^2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ dz \ dy \ dx = $

$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^2 sin(\varphi)(r^2\cdot cos^2(\varphi))\cdot r^2  \ dr \ d\theta \ d\varphi = $

$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^6 sin(\varphi)\cdot cos^2(\varphi)  \ dr \ d\theta \ d\varphi = $

$\int_{0}^{\pi / 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^6 sin(\varphi)\cdot (1-sin^2(\varphi))  \ dr \ d\theta \ d\varphi $.

It should be easy to end the calculation from here because it reduced to calcullating one dimentional integral over $\varphi$.

Comment: Rewriting $\sin\varphi\cos^2\varphi d\varphi$ as $d[-\tfrac13\cos^3\varphi]$ would be more helpful than $\sin\varphi(1-\sin^2\varphi)d\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is $ \, \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^²}}z^2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ dz \ dy \ dx$

To do this integral in spherical coordinates, let's first understand the region we are integrating the function over, which is part of a sphere of radius $2$ centered at the origin in the first octant.

From the upper bound of $z, \, z^2 = 4 - x^2 - y^2 \implies x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ is the sphere. We also notice that the lower bounds of $x, y, z$ are zero which means it is part of the sphere in the first octant. Now that we know our region, let's convert this into spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \cos \phi$

Also $dV = \rho^2 \sin \phi \, d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta$

So our triple integral of the given function over this region in spherical coordinates will be -

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2} \rho^6 \cos^2 \phi \, \sin \phi \,\ d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta = \frac{64 \pi}{21}$